# How to make Only Some Views touchable while making the others (like RelativeLayout) not touchable

Tags: android

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

The above code is to make the whole window not touchable.

However, the button inside this window is also being not Touchable, while I want it to be clickable.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Window w = getWindow();
w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setClickable(true);
b.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

How can I make on that button touchable?

Answer (score 2):

The other views in your layout shouldnt register onclicks unless you register them to. Whats the behavior you expected from setting the entire window to not be touchable?

EDIT: this code can be used to set any settings on just about any view as long as you want them all the same. For setting a number of views to be non clickable just throw them all into a view[] array and itterate through them like this

```
TextView a,b,c;
EditText d,e,f;
RelativeLayout g,h,i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(){


//intstatiate and inflate all your views....you should know how to do that

View[] viewHolder = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};
for(int i = 0; viewHolder.length>i; i++){

    viewHolder[i].setClickable(false);

}
```

This will do exactly what you want but unless the other views are taking focus you shouldnt have to do that. But it will work.

Answer (score 0):

By using this code:

```
  Window w = getWindow();
  w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

The whole window will be set as not touchable. Alternatively, you can use onClickListener for each View you added in your XML. even layouts can have their own click listener

Comment: okay but how? i mean how can I make a View Not Touchable instead of the whole window?

Comment: You shouldnt have to do that. Is there some other behavior taking place that makes you want to do that?